# Confusion about convex function on compact set

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry

In the paper

*Yau, Shing-Tung*, [**Non-existence of continuous convex functions on certain Riemannian manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01351342), Math. Ann. 207, 269-270 (1974). [ZBL0261.53036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0261.53036)., S.T.Yau proved that there does not exists a non-trivial convex function on complete Riemannian manifold with finite volume. But the function $f=|x|$ is convex on $[-1,1]$ and $[-1,1]$ has finite volume. I am confused about that. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: $[-1,1]$ is a manifold with boundary. They are probably talking about just manifolds. Can you do the same on the circle?

Comment: The interval $[-1,1]$ is not a smooth manifold and, hence, not a Riemannian manifold. Sometimes differential geometers consider manifolds with boundary, but then most would state specifically that they allow nonempty boundary. In the latter case, the two notions of completeness (geodesic completeness and metric completeness) are no longer equivalent.